# No puedo subir contenedor a Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, contenedores

Buen día,

Soy nuevo trabajando con docker y google cloud, en donde tengo una imagen de wildfly aplication server y de la cual creé un contenedor. El contenedor lo he trabajado desplegando distintas aplicaciones sobre él.

Tengo el problema que cuando quiero subir el contenedor que he trabajado(con todas mis apps ya instalas en él) a Google Container Registry utilizando los comandos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

docker tag [SOURCE_IMAGE] [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

docker push [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

El error que tengo es que me está subiendo la imagen en limpio, más no el contenedor que he trabajado.

Si utilizo el comando con el ID de contenedor más no con el ID de imagen tengo el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando los comandos que no son? o tengo un error de entendimiento de lo que quiero hacer?